# SharePoint 2013 Search and Office Web Apps

Tags: 2013, search

Is there a way to use office web apps to display search results in SharePoint 2013? If so, how?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Why do you NOT want to show search results in SharPoint? What is the driver for wanting them to show in web apps, and what web app do you want to show this in? Excel? Word?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great document to achieve what you need. [Install office web apps](http://melcher.it/2013/05/install-office-web-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-2013-with-pdf-preview/)

Remember that you will need a server only for office web apps